# Format the data into hierarchical JSON tree in python

Tags: python, json

Now I need to build an API that contains one JSON object. 
However, the data contains id, name, parend_id so that I need to recursively format the data so that I can get a hierarchical JSON object.

For example, the data in my database:

```
id | name           |  parend_id
----------------------------------
1  |  google        |  79
2  |  yahoo         |  98
3  |  google_cloud  |  1
4  |  XXX           |  1
5  |  YYY           |  4
```

Finally what I want is one JSON object like

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "google",
    "children": {
      "3": "google_cloud",
      "4": {
        "name": XXX,
        "children": {
          "5": YYY
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need of top level company is only the id 1, so one JSON object is enough. I have written some recursive functions to build the tree but all failed, some problems like automatically add "children" key, etc.

Thanks for all help and comments

Comment: where does `2 yahoo` fit here? your input and expected output don't look consistent. Please post the code you have tried as well

Comment: its not valid json

Comment: agreed with @VivekKalyanarangan  and where should be parent_id in your json

Comment: There are more than 300 companies in my database, what I want is just the json tree belongs to Google (id 1), so the id 2 Yahoo will not be used (This is another top level).

Comment: @Narendra the pid now is becoming a hierarchical relationship in the json, like id=1 google has children id=3&4, meanwhile, id=4 has a child 5. More like a multiple selector: